difference between two "long" multiplications
I have a difference between two multiplications with, say, $n$ terms each. The terms in the second multiplication are the same as those in the previous one, plus a "perturbation", that is
$\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i - \prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i+\epsilon_i)$
I would like to rearrange the difference above, into something like
$\sum_{i \neq h}^{n} (\prod_{i \neq h}x_i)\epsilon_h +...$
Is there a more "elegant" way of writing this expression? One involving fewer terms, or more compact than what I wrote above?

Well, $$\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i+b_i)=\sum_{S\subseteq {1,\cdots, n}} \prod_{j\in S}a_j\prod_{k\notin S} b_k$$ which can be grouped by cardinality of $S$ and be turned into $$\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{S\subseteq {1,\cdots, n}\ \lvert S\rvert =j} \left(\left(\prod_{j\in S} b_j\right)\left(\prod_{j\notin S} a_j\right)\right)$$

It sort of depends what you want to emphasize and do with it later, for example do you need a grouping by the different $\varepsilon$-monomials or something else.

The best you can do is$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i+\eps_i)=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i+\sum_{j=1}^n\eps_j\prod_{\substack{i=1\\ i\neq j}}^nx_i+\sum_{1\leq j<k\le n}\eps_j\eps_k\prod_{\substack{i=1\\ i\neq j,k}}^nx_i+\cdots+\prod_{j=1}^n\eps_j$$
Even more compactly,
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i+\eps_i)=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{1\le j_1<\cdots<j_r\le n}\prod_{k=1}^r\eps_{j_k}\prod_{\substack{i=1\\ i\neq j_k}}^nx_i$$
I assume you want to ignore everything that is of the order $\eps^2$ or $\eps^3$, and so the first expression is probably more useful.
Hope this helps. :)

super helpful!!! thank you
